# why the bitset's constructor has argument string::charT zero, string::charT one)

Tags: c++

```
bitset<bits>::bitset (const string& str,string::size_type str_idx,string::size_type str_num,string::charT zero)
bitset<bits>::bitset (const string& str,string::size_type str_idx, string::size_type str_num,string::charT zero,string::charT one)
```

and someone say:Throw invalid_argument if one of the characters is neither ’0’/zero nor ’1’/one.
but I can set ’1’/zero nor ’0’/one as argument and didn't throw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to allow you to construct a `bitset` from a string such as "xoxxox" where the bit values happen not to be represented as '0' and '1'. There's no constraint on what you pass as the zero and one parameters.

But if the string contains any characters that do not match your selected zero and one values, then you get an exception - e.g. `bitset<3>("xoA", 3, 'o', 'x')` will fail because of the 'A'.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset